# Solr searches with apostrophes only works partially

Tags: solr

I'm trying to perform a search on a field that contains names. I'm trying to figure out why I can't query names with apostrophes. If I search for "O'", I get the results I expect (things like O'Brien, O'Farrell, O'Connell etc.). If I search for the name "O'Brien", I get the results I expect. But if I search for "O'B" or anything other than the full name or just "O'", I get no results.
FYI, in the preceding examples, I don't actually include the double quotes. The field in question uses the following fieldtype (custom type created to ensure I can search for names that end in y - without it, I couldn't find "Icy"):

```
<fieldType name="trname" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
    <!-- Case insensitive stop word removal.
         enablePositionIncrements=true ensures that a 'gap' is left to
         allow for accurate phrase queries.
    -->
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
            ignoreCase="true"
            words="stopwords.txt"
            format="wordset"
            />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**: I just noticed the title of the question was totally wrong!

Comment: So what is your query? My initial guess is that your WordDelimiterFilterFactory splits tokens on `'`  ("Non-alphanumeric characters (discarded): "hot-spot" → "hot", "spot"")

Comment: Hi, per my examples, the queries are FirstName:O'Brien*, FirstName:O'B*, FirstName:O'Br* etc. First works, the others do not.

Comment: When you're querying by wildcards, analysis does not take place (except for multitermaware filters, such as the lowercasefilter). Since the tokens are being split by your worddelimterfactory (on `'`), there won't be any tokens to match against on the query side. Create a separate field without the word delimiter filter and use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When querying using wildcards, most analysis does not take place - that means that the tokens you're searching against are not the same as when you're querying.

The WordDelimiterFilter will split tokens based on `'`, meaning that when you're indexing content, you'll get separate tokens for each part of the word - i.e. `O` and `Brien`. When you're searching, that split will not happen, and Lucene will try to match a single token - `O'Brien` against the tokens that has been indexed. Since there is no token matching `O'Brien` (since the term was split into multiple tokens when indexing), you won't get a hit.

The solution is to create a field that matches the wildcards you expect to use - in this case, probably a field with just the WhitespaceTokenizer and LowercaseFilter (which should work with wildcards as it's multitermaware).

Using multiple different fields with the same content is expected, and you can use `copyField` to make sure that the same content is indexed into multiple fields, and then processed differently depending on how you're going to query them. That way you can have one field you search against when you expect Brien to match O'Brien, and one that you can use for wildcard searching, where that might not be the case.